# Java Intellij - setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)) is not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to fetch the data in my database I am using `MYSQL` as my database and `intellij` for my  **GUI.**
Now I have a problem the `setModel` is not working. I am getting errors.

```
java: method executeQuery in interface java.sql.Statement cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I don't know if it's an outdated function or I coded wrong. I am using **JDK 1.8.0_202** and **Mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar** and **rs2xml.jar**

Here is my code.

```
Connection conn;
Statement stmt;

     void table_products(){
            try{
    
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyBakery?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                Statement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM products");
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                table_products.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    
            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

Here is the list of my import:

```
    import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
    
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.sql.*;
```

Here is my JFrame:

```
   public Product(JFrame parent){
        super(parent);
        setTitle("Bakery Inventory System");
        setContentPane(registerPanel);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(550,600));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(320,200));
        setModal(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


        productAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                registerProduct();
                dispose();
            }
        });
        productCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dispose();
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

and not with `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel`. As you're using a `PreparedStatement`, you should use this type, to make the IDE aware of the available methods:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM products");
```

Using a `PreparedStatement` however is rather pointless in your code, as you're not providing any parameters and the statement is only executed once. Thus changing your code to this is probably the best solution:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products");
```

You should furthermore avoid declaring variables like `conn` or `stmt` as class members unless you have a valid reason to do so. Additionally your code is missing proper resource handling as neither the DB connection nor the statements or the result are properly closed.

All in all this would be a proper implementation:

```
try (final Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyBakery?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
     final Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products");) {
    table_products.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()

Comment: try {
            final Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyBakery?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
            final Statment = conn.createStatement();
            final ResultSet rs = Statment.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products");
            table_products.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

            }catch(SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

i followed you said but it gives me error  "java: <identifier> expected"

Comment: final Statment = conn.createStatement();  say java: <identifier> expected

Comment: @RayParas I updated the last code snippet...

Comment: i think the setModel is not working i copied your code and it gives cannot resolve method setModel.. the error message 

 java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setModel(javax.swing.table.TableModel)
  location: variable table_products of type javax.swing.JScrollPane 

sorry i am new on java programming

Comment: void table_products(){
         try (final Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/MyBakery?serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
              final Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
              final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products");) {
              table_products.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
         }
    }

Comment: Probably better to update the code as part of the question. Is it working for you now?

Comment: @RayParas please update your question. Reading code from the comments is close to impossible...

Comment: From your error message it looks like `table_products` is of type `javax.swing.JScrollPane`. But the table model can only be set on a [`JTable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setModel(javax.swing.table.TableModel))

Comment: okay i will close it, i will fix again

Comment: it's okay now thank you for your help and guide and tips

Comment: Glad it's working, especially since I wrote part of it ;)